# Weird Google chrome image bug

Tags: css, image, google-chrome

I can't seem to find an answer to this rather interesting problem. In google chrome, images that have a set width and/or height, either using attributes, inline styling or css styling, refuse to show up on the page on initial load. They only seem to appear after there has been some page activity. Yet, if you let the images load to their natural size they display on page load perfectly fine. The images can be seen as it works in other browsers and when inspecting elements in chrome the image is display in the popup window.

Any know how to fix this?

Comment: I've never seen this in Chrome. Are you running any extensions? That might cause this behavior.

Comment: This sounds more like a bandwidth issue than anything else. If you give an image width/height attributes but its a high-res or otherwise large file size, the height and width isn't going to make a difference on the load time. Chrome, IE, Opera, FireFox all have different methods of how they load images in general, example I think in this case, Chrome is preloading the image where as IE or firefox progressively loads the image.

Comment: No extensions or anything, and chrome is up to date. No bandwidth issue as I have unlimited bandwidth and everything is running locally. Never encountered this before, but as of 24hrs ago when running tests on the new software im developing this issue has arisen.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of the bug? Even if we can't test it, someone might be able to find a glitch in your code that causes the problem.

Comment: http://coreyyoungcorp.com/chromebug/

uploaded to my test server. when the page loads, the bottom of the screen should display a row of images. i left a broken image link in there so you can see where. you can click the right side of the screen to get the gallery moving or click where one of the images is supposed to appear at the bottom. click the middle of the screen once and then once again, which will hide and show the row of images at the bottom, and then the images will appear as normal.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos when I said and/or with width and height i meant setting the specific measurement of one or both, rather than just one and the other as 'auto', and "after some page activity" means when you begin clicking around and whatnot. read my previous comment to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define what you mean by: 'after some page activity'.

You also mentioned that the it happens when you have set width AND/OR height which leads me to believe in some of your testing your ommiting width OR height so it can be calculated by the browser. if that is the case then yes the image will never look proper and the elements will have no size on initial page load UNTIL the image is downloaded, the browser inspects the image and determines the dimensions missing to create the bounding box.

Edit:

After looking at your online site, my previous comment explains the gist of it but I can see that you're setting a width of 'auto' which requires the browser to load the image first and detect the sizes. Which will cause a delayed 'reflow' in the browser rendering. Set your widths and heights otherwise they will need to calculated by the client browser. And if you have not so good pc it looks sluggish. On my system if i hard refresh with no cache sometimes i get all the thumbs and other times I don't and the delay is very noticeable.

So in short make your images always have a width AND height.

Edit:

You also have some 404 errors that can cause some latency. http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120725_0C_3N6/1/details/

Edit:

I think your only option is to load the bg image first by getting it higher up in the order of resources downloaded so it loads in as fast as possible to be rendered. 
One trick might be to load the bg image in a hidden div to preload it right away so the browser downloads it first. And even if you do that you should expect to see some flash of black background while you wait for the high res shot to download and get loaded. Can't set widths and heights on background images anyways. Going further you can speed up the response time maybe by loading all the thumbnails with an AJAX call AFTER page loads so they don't even compete with the big photo shot and start downloading until the dom is fully loaded. You can even put a nice effect in there to maybe fade in the thumbnails loading or something to that effect.

Comment: ahh, issue solved... for the most part. for the large display of the image that takes up the full page, I'm not able to set both a width AND a height because of different screen resolutions, so how do I get around this?

Comment: Shouldn't be too bad for the big image, the render should happen quick. But if you have many with no width or height then your leaving the calculations up to the client machine (and browser). You also have some 404 erros on the page that can cause some slowness because of the latency. See my edit, link to webpage test report

Comment: its just the first background image that has the problem, since it's the one the loads with page load. the others render fine.

Comment: I did not have enough room to fit it all in a comment so I answered above.

Comment: what appears to be a background image isnt actually a background image, it's an img tag as well, but yea you can set width and height of backgrounds using the css style "background-size". Strange that all browsers seem to support it and have done for ages but it never appears in dreamweaver.